How can I add json_table in to createQueryBuilder (typeorm)
I tried to run:
    return this.myRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('s')
      .select(['s.add', '_id'])
      .innerJoin(
        `JSON_TABLE(
        json_field,
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS (
            _id VARCHAR(255) PATH "$._id"
        )
    )`,
        'j',
        '1=1',
      )
      .where('s.add= :myAdd', { myAdd: '003' })
      .getRawMany();

But I'm getting  ER_TOO_LONG_IDENT: Identifier name 'json_table(
code: 'ER_TOO_LONG_IDENT',
errno: 1059,
How can I use json_table in createQueryBuilder?
